# how to add autoreload to ptipython?

Tags: ipython, prompt-toolkit

In ipython, we could use the following code to enable auto reload feature.

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Now I am using ptipython, I could just type them every time using ptipython, but is there anything that could be automatically executed? such as .bashrc for bash shell.

There is a config.py which will be automatically run. But

```
%load_ext autoreload
```

is not python code, so looks like I can't put them here. Any other solutions to avoid type them manually?

Comment: IPython has [startup files](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files) which it runs on start. Hopefully that will work with ptipython too.

Comment: I tried, but that doesn't help. But good to know how to do it in plain ipython. thanks.